# How to test all values in a ModelBindingContext.ValueProvider were consumed by a custom model binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, model, model-binding

I'm writing a unit test for a custom model binder (MVC 3) and want to confirm all the values I passed in through my ValueProvider are consumed by the binder (meaning the binder read them and bound them to the model object).  (I also want a test case to confirm that a ValueProvider with extra values are not consumed)

Here's the (working) code for my test:

```
    <Test()> _
    Public Sub Should_Bind_Example_Payment_Method_To_Model()
        'arrange
        Dim testBindingContext As New ModelBindingContext() With {
            .ModelName = "MyModel",
            .ValueProvider = New NameValueCollectionValueProvider(
                New NameValueCollection() From {
                    {"Param1", "val1"},
                    {"Param2", "val2"},
                }, Nothing),
            .ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(Nothing, GetType(MyModelType))
        }

        dim testControllerContext as new ControllerContext()
        Dim modelBinder As New MyCustomModelBinder()

        'act
        Dim generatedModel As MyModelType = modelBinder.BindModel(testControllerContext, testBindingContext)

        'assert
        Assert.AreEqual("val1", generatedModel.Param1)
        Assert.AreEqual("val2", generatedPaymentMethod.Param2)

        Assert.IsTrue(testBindingContext.ModelState.IsValid)
    End Sub
```

I want to add a line like this (this is obviously invalid code)

```
Assert.IsTrue(testBindingContext.ValueProvider.AllValuesConsumed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

A) Create a mock of IValueProvider that has the logic to test if you consume all.

B) Accept multible assertions, but extract them in to a method to keep the unittest short, simple and readable.

I would chose B) because of simplicity -- unless i expected similar tests involving IValueProvider. I would call the assertion method something like `AssertThatAllValuesAreConsumed(testBindingContext)`.

Regards,
Morten

Comment: I don't mind multiple assertions, but what do I need to assert?

Comment: I don't think there is a magic bullit here. You need to know how the binder should consume, and assert on those expectations. The alternative is the mock object, that can tell if all values have been read.

Comment: That's precisely the question.  Are there any assumptions that a ModelValueProvider follows in consuming values or do I need to that via a mock.

Comment: Hmmm... exactly what do you want to test? In your question, you state that you want to test the binder. How another object -- your  provider -- behaves to provide the binder with data, should not be explored in a unit-test. That would make it an integration test. You should just assume that provider does what it is supposed to do.